# Distributing a function into an existing inner-product (math for quantum chemistry)

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, quantum-mechanics, chemistry

**Question:**

Can functions *outside* bra-ket notation be distributed *into* the bra and ket? Since I am uncertain exactly how to ask this question, I include the problem below. Essentially, I don't know how eq. (2-55) results from eq. (2-54). Can $\phi_0$ be distributed into the bra and ket in eq. (2-54)?

**Edit:**

Per @Tortar's comment regarding typos, I have attached an image of the problem from the book in lieu of my LaTeX. Upon further review, the PDF to which @Tortar is referring may be a different edition of the aforementioned book, which is where I assume the typo discrepancy arises!

[image: Page 29 from Mathematics for Quantum Chemistry, 2005 Dover Edition, by J.M. Anderson]

**What I have Tried:**

My first thought was to distribute $\phi_1$ in eq. (2-54) to the $f_1$ ket and the $\phi_0$ bra; however, this would yield a strange equation that doesn't look like it would lead to the solution.

\begin{equation}
\phi_{1} = N_1^{1/2}(f_1 - <\phi_0\phi_1 | f_1\phi_1>) \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Revisiting the definition of the inner product (from [here](http://eng-web1.eng.famu.fsu.edu/%7Edommelen/quantum/style_a/dot.html)), though, the distribution idea seems shaky at best. Given a function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, the inner product is defined below.

\begin{equation}
<f|g> = \int f(x)^*g(x) \, dx \tag{2}
\end{equation}

I think this means that if I choose to "distribute" $\phi_1$ as in eq. (1), the result is shown below:

\begin{equation}
<\phi_0\phi_1 | f_1\phi_1> = \int (\phi_0\phi_1)^*(f_1\phi_1)\, dx \tag{3}
\end{equation}

Eq. (3) does not advance me toward the solution shown in eq. (2-55).

One thing thing that I think might be useful, but I am not sure how to use it, is the fact that given $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then $|z|^{2} = (\sqrt{zz^*})^2 = zz^*$. The last term in eq. (2-55) has the $|z|^{2}$ form, which is why I bring this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't distribute $\phi_1$ inside the inner product because $\phi_1$ is an element of a vector space instead the inner product $\langle\phi_0 | f_1\rangle$ is a scalar. The problem with your definition of inner product $\int f(x) g(x)$ is that it doesn't return a scalar indeed I think you should use $\int_a^b f(x) g(x)$.

---

A way to prove the relation in your book :

From
$$\phi_{1} = N_1^{-1/2}(f_1 - \langle\phi_0 | f_1\rangle\phi_0) $$

moving the norm on the left and applying the inner product with $\phi_1$ and using the axioms of an inner product and the assumption of your text you obtain that

$$N_1^{1/2} \overbrace{\langle\phi_1| \phi_1 \rangle}^{1} = N_1^{1/2} =  \langle (f_1 - \langle\phi_0 | f_1\rangle\phi_0)| \phi_1\rangle =\langle f_1| \phi_1 \rangle - \langle\phi_0 | f_1\rangle \overbrace{\langle\phi_0 | \phi_1 \rangle}^{0} =  \langle f_1| \phi_1 \rangle $$

substituting in $N_1^{1/2} = \langle f_1| \phi_1 \rangle $ the identities

$\phi_1 = N_1^{-1/2}(c\phi_0 + f_1)$ and
$c = -\langle\phi_0|f_1\rangle$ gives you

$$N_1^{1/2} = \langle f_1|N_1^{-1/2}(-\langle\phi_0|f_1\rangle\phi_0 + f_1) \rangle \implies$$

$$ N_1 = \langle f_1| f_1 \rangle - \langle\phi_0|f_1\rangle\ \langle f_1|\phi_0 \rangle =  \langle f_1| f_1 \rangle - |\langle\phi_0|f_1\rangle|^2 $$

Comment: Thank you kindly for your answer. I have updated the question to reflect the text from the book. How do you know that $N_1^{1/2} = <f_1 | \phi_1 >$? I don't understand this, and I am still not sure how your response leads to equation (2-55).

Comment: I filled the details, say to me if you find it clear!

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!!! This makes complete sense.